# How to access media files(images/videos) received in telegram on ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, 13.04

How to access files received in telegram . I have installed telegram on my ubuntu 14.04 . Where  I can find downloaded files ?

Comment: It's kinda confusing if you choose 13.04 and 14.04 as tags at the same time ;)

Comment: did you found the files as described below?

Answer (score 2):

### Using Telegram Web

If you select to download an image *Telegram Web* opens a dialog where you can freely choose the storage location.

### Using Telegram Desktop

If you select to download an image in *Telegram Desktop* there is no dialog - instead the file gets automatically stored in

```
~/Downloads/Telegram Desktop
```

**Change Default settings in Telegram Desktop**

You can change that by visiting the Settings in *Telegram Desktop* and uncheck the option *Don't ask download path for each file*

The settings dialog let you as well choose a *default folder*.

In addition there is a point *Automatic media download setting* which might be worth a look as well.

[image]